# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SimpleITK'

Tags: python, pip

I am encountering an error of "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SimpleITK'"

I am not sure why I am getting this error since I installed it:
[image]

In the image you can see that right after installing it and running a script, it says it isn't installed.

I even pip installed it in the modules directory: [image]

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like the pip you're using in from the base Anaconda environment, while the python you're executing is from somewhere else.  The python you'd what to run should also be in 'c:\User\Mikul Vineet\anaconda3\Scripts'.

Comment: This is solved by reading the error messages. When pip tells you: "Requirement already satisfied: <package name> in <path>", it is showing you that path for a reason. Similarly, when you start Python by specifying a complete path to the Python executable, there should be a good reason for that. If that is not enough of a hint, please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: When I do the where python command on cmd I get two directories. One is one I used above and the other is one without a Scripts folder. Is my installation for python wrong?

Comment: It's not unusual to have more than 1 Pythons installed.  That's the reason for virtual environments.  But you just have to make sure you're executing the proper one.